# Issues converting communication from serial port to UDP packets

Tags: sockets, serial-port, udp, crc

I have some (very) old software written in C, that was used for two devices that communicate via serial cable (RS232) - both sending and receiving messages.
Now the old devices are to be replaced by new modern ones that do not have serial ports, but only Ethernet.
Hence, the request now is to convert the old serial communication to UDP communication (C++ is the choice for the moment).
So, I have some questions about this "conversion":
**1)** Suppose there are two peers A and B. Should I implement a server and a client for each peer, i.e.: serverA+clientA (for device A) and serverB+clientB (for device B)? Or is there some other/different approach?...
**2)** The old serial communication had some CRC, probably to ensure some reliability. Is it CRC necessary to be implemented (in my custom messages) also on UDP communication or not?
Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** UDP is a connectionless protocol so there's no rigid client and server roles here. You simply have some code that handles receiving and some code that facilitates sending.

**2)** You don't need CRC for UDP. First, there's a FCS (CRC32) in each Ethernet frame. Then, there's a header checksum in IP packets. After all, checksum is already included in UPD datagram!

Please also consider the following things:

- In everyday life COM ports are long gone from the physical world, but they're still with us in the virtual form (even Android phones have COM ports). There are a lot of solutions for doing COM over USB/TCP/whatever. Some of them are PC apps, some of them are implemented in hardware (see Arduino's COM over USB),
- When an UDP datagram fails checksum test, it is dropped (usually) silently. So in UDP you don't have built-in capabilities to distinguish between "nothing was received" and "we received something but that's not a valid thing". Check [UDP-Lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP-Lite) if you want to handle these situations on the application level (it should simplify the porting process I believe).
- Default choice for transferring data is TCP, because it provides reliable delivery. UDP is recommended for users that care about being realtime and for those who can tolerate some data loss. Or for those who care about the resources.
- Choose TCP if you are going to send large amount of data or be ready to handle packet congestion on ports. Choose TCP if you plan to go wireless in future or be ready to handle periodical significant loss of packets.
- If your devices are really tiny or filled with other stuff, it is possible to operate directly on Level 2 (Ethernet).

Comment: It's exactly the answers I needed. Thanks also for the extra considerations, really appreciate it. I did have some idea about UDP communication, but I felt the need to be 100% sure. Better ask than sorry :) The devices in question are running embedded Linux on a LAN, that's why we opted for the UDP (TCP has much more overhead, I guess...). Kind regards, Stanley G.